# Spring-Boot: File system failure - configuration

Tags: spring-boot

Unfortunately, I stucked. 
Situation: My app run good, but when I fitted it with Spring-Boot-Security, the all css, js, img folder become unaccessible....

[My file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnLIL.png)

I tried to adopt the MVCConfig properties in my application.properties file, but it didn't work. :( 
(spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class to set security settings. Note that you need to specify unprotected urls as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/assets/**", "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```